# Apache + Python + Mongo: Object Ids aren't equal

Tags: django, apache, mongodb, pymongo

We are running two copies of a django-based application within an Apache instance. We have this python code when loading an object from the database:

```py
id = pymongo.objectid.ObjectId(hex_string)
d = self.collection.find_one({ '_id': id })
assert id == d['_id']
```

On one of the two applications (whichever we hit second) the assert fails. We've looked at the ids, and they are the same. Plus, when we change it to:

```py
assert str(id) == str(d['_id'])
```

The assert passes. On our development machines (Win 7 64-bit, django dev server instead of  Apache) this seems to work fine.

Stack: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Apache 2.2.14, Python 2.6.5, MongoDB 2.0, Pymongo 2.0.1

**Update:** We ran into another problem like this. We actually started referring to the objects as BSON object ids, and that fixed the second problem. However, the problem in this question is still occurring, even with using BSON object ids.

Comment: Are there any errors in the apache error_log file at the time when you see this behavior?

Comment: The only unexpected thing I see in the `error_log` (besides `DeprecationWarning`s that we are fixing, is: `TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html`

Comment: try to log the type of "d['_id']" and "id". what are they? and what are the values?

Comment: I will try to log them if I can figure out how to do that. I can tell you that we have turned debug on in django on the failing instance and looked at the 500 response we get back. They both represent themselves, for instance, as `ObjectId('47283de8cf9cc30d000000')` Plus, the exact same code works on the other application. I will edit the question to clarify that confounding factor.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a shot in the dark, but you aren't using sharding by any chance, are you? I haven't tested it, but it seems like there is a possibility of having two docs with the same _id if you shard on a non-_id field. Are you generating the _id values yourself or letting pymongo do it for you on insert?

Comment: Nope, no sharding. And we are letting pymongo create the ids for us.